# Seeking records for Thomas Chorley of Madras, India (born 1821, died 1843)?

Tags: 19th-century, india

Thomas Chorley:

- was born 1821 at Madras, India
- died 1843 at Madras, India

> "India Deaths and Burials, 1719-1948," database, FamilySearch
>   (https://familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:FGPT-1JR : 3 December 2014),
>   Thomas Chorley, 02 Feb 1843; citing ; FHL microfilm 521,843.

He may be related to my great grand father Rev Frank Iyanar CHORLEY.

Does anyone know how I may be able to learn more about the life of Thomas?

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  What is the specific question that you wish to ask?  Is it perhaps a marriage record for him that you seek?  Since it appears that he only lived until the age of 22 there would seem to be a strong possibility that he did not marry.

Comment: How do you know that Thomas Chorley was born in India? The burial record you cited has a birth date, but that is likely to be an estimate based on his age at death.

Comment: @PolyGeo I started to edit the title and re-tag the question to suggest a more productive avenue for answers that may be of more general interest.  However, that turned the question into a duplicate of http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/12289/1006, so I have rolled my edits back.

Comment: @JanMurphy if it gets turned into a duplicate then I think that may be better than remaining unanswered.

Comment: @PolyGeo In any case "how can I find out more about (one ancestor)" is very broad. However, I think your suggestion of narrowing the question down to a search of a single record type is too narrow.

Comment: There are whole books written about researching Europeans in India. So far as I know, cross referring to such books is not what Stack Exchange is about, but is it not the only sensible answer?