# Researching English/Christian families in India during first half of 19th century?

Tags: 19th-century, parish-register, india

Are there any online sources of information for (English) Christian families in India?

I'm particularly interested in the first half of the nineteenth century.

Comment: Hi, Jacqueline -- This question is not a good fit for our site because it is very broad.  Can you narrow the time frame or geographical area, or both, or focus your question in some other way?  We have no idea what you have looked for already.  Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) in the [help] for some guidelines. You can also run a search for other questions tagged India to see what resources have already been mentioned on the site.

Comment: hi, Jacqueline -- I've reworded your query to be more specific -- please edit it if it isn't in line with what you need to know.

Answer (score 3):

The [FIBIS](http://www.fibis.org/) (Families in British India Society) is an excellent starting point. They're a "a self-help organisation devoted to members researching their British India family history and the background against which their ancestors led their lives in India under British rule." You will have to subscribe to access all their data (currently £15 p.a.) but they have good explanatory material available free which can help shape your search.

Another site that may be of use is the [India Office Family History Search](http://indiafamily.bl.uk/UI/) produced by the British Library based on their own transcriptions.

I suspect you've already located the [FamilySearch](https://familysearch.org/wiki/en/India_Online_Genealogy_Records) page pointing to online resources, including the two I've mentioned and also their own collections of records.