# Finding records about members of the Indian Civil Service?

Tags: 19th-century, india

My grandmother was "in service" to a retired Indian Civil Servant. I have all his career details in the Indian Civil Service, but I would like to find out more about his actual life whilst he was in India; i.e. what were his actual duties, his social life, where did he actually live, and also what was his & his families "attitudes" with regard to the "locals", so I really need to contact an actual researcher in India.

My grandmother was "in service" to him, and his family, when he had returned to England upon retirement and it seems that (considering her life), that this period "in service" was important to her - hence my interest to find out more about her employer!

Comment: See https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/12289/sources-for-getting-started-on-researching-christian-families-in-india for some idea where to start. However, you will also need to research the 'social context' as you are unlikely to find the informaton you are looking for about one specific individual unless he was very prominent.

Comment: Welcome to G&FH SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format which is quite different from bulletin boards, discussion forums and other Q&A sites you may be used to.  If, after examining the duplicate question, you have more questions then I would encourage you to also ask them here as new questions.

Comment: @PolyGeo I would like to see this question improved so we can re-open it, since it is not about the same time period as the earlier question.  The earlier question is about the first half of the *nineteenth* century, which is much earlier than this question.

Comment: @JanMurphy good point - I've re-opened the question and changed the titles on both questions to help disambiguate them - I agree that the asker is likely to get a better answer by providing more details.

Comment: May we please get some information about the time period involved in this question?  You need not give names, but knowing the time period would be useful.

Comment: the gentleman arrived in Bombay 26th October 1867 (Assistant Collector, Magistrate and Forest Settlement Officer). His final position was July 1896 (Chief Secretary to the Government of Bombay, Political Dept.). At this time he is also an additional Member of The Legislative Council. He retires back to England in March 1897. I know that he played in the first ever game of Badminton in an indoor court on July 10th 1873. This was held at Sattara, Bombay Presidency (which was the cradle of the present Badminton Association game).